# Change crosstab cell background color

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to change report cell background color with case/switch conditions. I need to do so programmatically in the code *before* it loads at runtime, so we don't want to use Format Object from report editor.

We color cells depending on their values. Each row has different rules:

[image]

We don't need to have static rules because they keep changing from time to time, the rules table is stored in the database. So we check the first cell in each row and select the matching rule. This way we can get the colors from the rules table and assign them to the following cells in the same row.

How can we implement this functionality in C#?

Comment: Do you have fixed number of rows or they are dynamic?

Comment: They are dynamic.  Do you have any idea about how to do it :) ?

Comment: Is it possible to check the rules table in the SQL query that retrieves the dataset?  This would allow you to have a column in the dataset that indicates the color needed for row of data in your original dataset before the pivot.  Then the crosstab could evaluate this data to determine background color through a switch statement in the Format Object formula for background color.